# Find discrete transfer function from impulse response?

Tags: signal-processing, control-theory

This is the impulse response of a discrete system. X1 , X2, X3,X4 were unknowns and that's why the picture might not seem right. 
**X1=1, X2=5, X3=2, X4=7**

[image]

I might have done this right but I'm having second thoughts since I haven't practised much on these.$$T(k)=\frac{Y(k)}{δ(k)}$$ where δ(k) is the input Y(k) the output and T(k) my transfer function$$Y(k)=δ(k)T(k)\\Y(k)=δ(k)(5u(k-1)-3u(k-2)+5(k-3)-7u(k-4)$$Z-transforming I get: $$G(z)=\frac{5z}{z-1}z^{-1}-\frac{3z}{z-1}z^{-2}+\frac{5z}{z-1}z^{-3}-\frac{7z}{z-1}z^{-4}$$We can go on and simplify ... It seemed too easy so if anyone could confirm I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are dealing with a finite impulse response consisting of $4$ taps (non-zero elements). In that case the impulse response can be described (in time domain) as an impulse train

$$
h[n] = \sum_{k=1}^4X_k \delta[n-kn_k],n\in \mathbb{Z},
$$

where $n_k$ is the delay (shift) of the $k$-th tap. Now you can find the transfer function $\mathcal{Z}(h[n])$ by using $\mathcal{Z}(\delta[n-l])=z^{-l},l\in\mathbb{Z}$, and the linearity of the $\mathcal{Z}$ transform.

P.S.: Yes, this is an easy exercise, however, your solution is wrong and your notation is a bit sloppy.

Comment: I understand that it is sloppy, I haven't had the time to study as much as I wanted. Could you tell me what is wrong in my solution?

Comment: @JohnKatsantas The expression for the time-domain impulse response ($T(k)$ in your notation) is wrong. It should be a sum of (shifted) deltas not $u[n]$'s.

Comment: It seems much better that way. Thank you. I still get the right values with the u[n]'s though don't I?That's why I chose these coefficients. It's just common practice to do it with deltas instead of step I guess.

Comment: @JohnKatsantas If you consider a step function as an input, you are computing the (Z-trasform of the) *step* response not the *impulse* response.

Comment: No T(k) is my transfer function, not the input. I still have the input δ[n] or δ[k] in my solution.